# Paste but don't execute command in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

My target is to show the Windows command prompt and display a command on the command line without executing it. Therefore, if I want to display the command `echo Hello`, I want the command prompt to be started and display:

`C:\Windows\System32>echo Hello_`

... where _ is the blinking cursor waiting for the user to press a key.

To accomplish this, I've tried either to create a shortcut to the Windows command prompt executable, that has its "Target" changed to:
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ...`

or a bat file containing:

`cmd.exe /k ...`

... where /k stands for:

> /k : Carries out the command specified by string and continues

This makes the command prompt continue to live and not terminate the way the /c switch acts.

Any idea how to achieve this result?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve what you want with `cmd` alone. It could be done with a VBScript, though.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /k @title MyCmd"
sh.AppActivate "MyCmd"
sh.SendKeys "echo Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had test and the result success. But dont know is this what you search..

1. Make a notepad and write

set /p id=hello

1. save the notepad by .bat format
2. Make a shorcut and select the notepad you save before
3. Run the shorcut.

Is that what you wish?

Comment: It's stupid that we have to use this workaround, but it works.